# SD card seating issue?

Tags: boot-issues

I have an SD card that boots to a USB stick for Raspbmc. I have to hold my finger down on the card to get it to boot. Has anybody seen anything like that before?

I'm thinking I may have damaged something when I forgot the SD card was in it and it bounced around in a shoebox for about 24 hours of driving.

Comment: Yes, I would say that kind of abuse (for a lack of a better word) could cause such an issue (assuming vertically violent driving, bouncing up and down).  It the seating noticeably insecure? Does it wiggle?

Comment: Thanks for the input. The good news is, the connector isn't broken. The bad news, it seems the SD card is damaged internally in some way. It's happy enough in my laptop - I used "H2TestW" to do a full R/W check; but the laptop physically mounts it differently. The NOOBS card mine shipped with boots fine, and the soldering joints passed a cursory magnified visual inspection.

Comment: How very strange… I've known SD cards to simply go wonky after a while. Who made the card? What model? Perhaps others have reported similar issues.

Comment: Kingston 4GB, Class 6.

Answer (score 2):

You're not the only person to have done this kind of thing; I'm sure I've noticed a few people complaining about having broken the SD card slot off altogether.

Someone has [instructions for replacing it](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Repair-a-Broken-Raspberry-Pi-SD-Card-Slot/). I imagine you don't want or have to go that far, but it may provide some insight -- if you are having to press down, it could be that one of the connections has come loose, and levering the card forces them together.  If so, it might be easily resoldered.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem my SD card slot arrived broken. This was my fix:

If you have the raspberry pi in a case, glue some foam/rubber/something in the inside bottom of the case underneath the SD card slot so that it applies upward pressure to the SD towards the connectors.